# retrieving value and saving it via form and $_GET (PHP)

Tags: php, html, session

I have a kink that I need to solve.

I am working with a form which looks kind of like

```
<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="get">
        <h1>Score</h1>
        <p>Uno
        <input type="number" size="10" name="First" value="{$First}"/>
        </p>

        <p>Dos
        <input type="number" size="10" name="Second" value="{$Second}"/>
        </p>

        <p>Tres
        <input type="number" size="10" name="Third" value="{$Third}"/>
        </p>

        <p>Quattro
        <input type="number" size="10" name="Fourth" value="{$Fourth}"/>
        </p>

        <button type="submit">Hit to submit your inputs</button>
    </form>
```

And I also have some php code to retreive these inputs which looks like the following

```
$First = $_GET['First'];
$Second = $_GET['Second']; 
$Third = $_GET['Third'];
$Fourth = $_GET['Fourth'];
```

And then I print these inputs made using a simple

```
echo $First, $Second, $Third, $Fourth;
```

The problem at hand is that I need to perform a calculation based on these four variables first, and then print out the result after that they have been manipulated.

I have created a function to do this

```
function calculateIt(){
$overall = $first+$second+$third+$fourth/2;
return $overall;
}
```

then I call the function

```
$call = calculateIt();
```

But once I echo this call out, It return 0. So I am guessing that the $_GET is not storing the results long enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have parameters to pass the values of those variables, because variables inside a function have scope only withing that function, in other words, the variables inside a function can be only used inside that function,unless and until you use `global` which is considered as bad practice, so have parameters and pass the values like

```
function calculateIt($first, $second, $third, $fourth){
   $overall = $first+$second+$third+$fourth/2;
   return $overall;
}
```

So when you call, you need to pass the values here like

```
calculateIt(2, 5, 6, 8); //You can replace digits with local variables having numeric values
```

[**Learn Variable Scope**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Side Note : Use `isset` to check if those indexes are set or not, else throw errors to the user

Answer (score 0):

Your function returns a calculated value of some values ($first, $second ...), but these values are not defined within the function. Therefore it returns 0. (It's just caluclating with values that have value 0)

```
function calculateIt(){
$overall = $first+$second+$third+$fourth/2;
return $overall;
}
```

Pass the values to the functions, like this:

```
function calculateIt($first = null, $second = null, $third = null, $fourth = null){
//Assigning the values in the declartion of the functions make it easy to
//check wether or not the valeus or ok for calculation
//
if ($first === null || $second === null || $third === null || $fourth === null) {
   return 0; //return 0 when not all values are sent.
}

//Do the calculation now when values are ok, and return calculated value
$overall = $first+$second+$third+$fourth/2;
return $overall;
}
```

Of course you could do more checking, above was just an example...